# Bounded exponential random number Java

Tags: java, random, exponential-distribution

I want to generate random numbers on bounded exponential distribution in Java but the formula `x = log(1-u)/(−λ)` (Here u is a uniform random number between `[0,1)` ) does not generate bounded exponential random number.

Please let me know how can I generate a bounded exponential distribution based random number in JAVA.

Comment: What do you mean by bounded? Your quantile function is correct.

Comment: By Bounded I mean to say all generated number should lie in range of 1-100.

Comment: Before I wade in with something pragmatic, what are you wanting to use the random numbers for?

Comment: There is a set of experiment to be run for research on hadoop on basis on the exponential distribution based random number having a mean of 50 and number lying in the range of 1 to 100.

Comment: Hum. That's tricky. I was going to suggest that you apply the quantile function then discard the outliers. But that suffers from two effects: your mean will go off, and you'll introduce statistical bias since you should never discard random numbers. I think you need to start from scratch: write out the cdf for the special distribution that you want, then construct the quantile function from that. You might get away with an affine transformation of p and a recalibration of lambda to recover the correct mean. Unfortunately that's a couple of hours work for me and I don't have the time.

Comment: Try the mathematics site?

Comment: I will look into it. Thanks @Bathsheba

Answer (score 0):

Wrt your question, you could try to rescale your U(0,1) rng, say for range [A...B], `L` is lambda

```
a = 1.0 - exp(-A*L); // so that log(1-a)/(-L) = A;
b = 1.0 - exp(-B*L); // so that log(1-b)/(-L) = B;

// now sampling 
u = a + (b - a) * Rng();
v = log(1-u)/(-L);
```

In your case A = 1, B = 100

BTW, `u` and `1-u` have the same distribution, so you could use `log(u)` instead of `log(1-u)`, saves you a substraction

Comment: A problem with this approach is that `L` will no longer be the mean of the distribution. `L` requires rescaling too.

Comment: @Bathsheba that is correct, but I cannot find in the original question the desire to preserve `L` as a mean. From the other hand, `L` still has meaning of rate in my approach